# Intercom rails API key to access token updation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, intercom

Hi am new to Ruby On Rails. I got an email from intercom regarding depricating API keys. Am using Intercom-rails but i didnt see any updation changes in git can any one help me thanks in advance.

Comment: Oh i see you asked the same question at the git repo. ... wait... Maybe you have to ask in the helpcenter. I also couldn't find a change in the git repo.

Comment: @amarradi am using create event and user data fetching functions do you know how to change API key to Access token ?

Comment: No I don&#39;t. I&#39;m only working with a &quot;stock rails&quot;.  I created an account a and I could imagine that you can change the API key at the site. Like Google or Facebook

Comment: I found that Intercom ruby needs to be updated to access token hence i replaced mu api key with access token it works fine for me and am using its for create event also.

Answer (score 0):

I found that Intercom ruby needs to be updated to access token hence i replaced my api key with access token it works fine for me. I am using api  for create event and current user manager.